# NestJS JWT Module Issues

Tags: javascript, typescript, jwt, nestjs, passport.js

Having issues with the JWTModule in NestJS. I continuously get this error, even when I pass the secret directly into the configuration instead of through my env file. I can't figure out what I am missing.

```
Error: secretOrPrivateKey must have a value
```

Quick rundown of how this will work.

1. Client calls /auth/login with { username: string, password: string }
2. LocalStrategy Guard will call AuthService's validateUser method, which calls ldapServices authenticateUser method and returns the user.
3. From there, I have to get the user data from ldap and combine it with some user data we have in our mongo db. This all works fine.
4. After passing through the guard, it will call AuthService's login method. Which should create and sign the payload with the JWT, using the JwtService (provided by NestJS). This is where my issue occurs.

Here are the files and their code:

app.controller.ts

```
import { Controller, Get, Post, Request, UseGuards } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { AuthService } from './providers/auth/auth.service';
import { LocalAuthGuard } from './providers/auth/local.strategy';

@Controller()
export class AppController {
  constructor(private readonly authService: AuthService) {}

  @UseGuards(LocalAuthGuard)
  @Post('/auth/login')
  async login(@Request() req) {
    return this.authService.login(req.user);
  }
}
```

auth.module.ts

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import { AuthController } from './auth.controller';
import { UserModule } from './../../endpoints/user/user.module';
import { PassportModule } from '@nestjs/passport';
import { LocalStrategy } from './local.strategy';
import { JwtModule, JwtService } from '@nestjs/jwt';
import { UserService } from './../../endpoints/user/user.service';
import { LdapService } from './../ldap/ldap-service';
import { jwtConstants } from './constants';
import { JwtStrategy } from './jwt.strategy';

@Module({
  imports: [
    UserModule,
    PassportModule,
    JwtModule.register({
      secret: '2I*5f5OE9tlGIbg*3Q*C',
      signOptions: { expiresIn: '12h' },
    }),
  ],
  providers: [AuthService, LocalStrategy, LdapService],
  controllers: [AuthController],
  exports: [AuthService],
})
export class AuthModule {}
```

auth.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { LdapService } from '../ldap/ldap-service';
import { UserService } from './../../endpoints/user/user.service';
import { JwtService } from '@nestjs/jwt';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
  constructor(
    private readonly ldapService: LdapService,
    private readonly userService: UserService,
    private readonly jwtService: JwtService
  ) {}

  async validateUser(username: string, pass: string): Promise<any> {
    const authenticated = await this.ldapService.authenticateUser(
      username,
      pass,
    );

    if (authenticated === true) {
      console.log(authenticated, username, pass)
      return await this.userService.getUserById(username);
    }
    return null;
  }

  async login(user: any) {
    const payload = { ...user, sub: user.accountName };
    console.log(process.env.JWT_SECRET, payload);
    return {
      access_token: this.jwtService.sign(payload),
    };
  }
}
```

local.strategy.ts

```
import { Strategy } from 'passport-local';
import { AuthGuard, PassportStrategy } from '@nestjs/passport';
import { Injectable, UnauthorizedException } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';

@Injectable()
export class LocalStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy) {
  constructor(private authService: AuthService) {
    super();
  }

  async validate(username: string, password: string): Promise<any> {
    const user = await this.authService.validateUser(username, password);
    if (!user) throw new UnauthorizedException();
    return user;
  }
}

@Injectable()
export class LocalAuthGuard extends AuthGuard('local') {}
```

I am sure I am missing something small. Appreciate the help.

Comment: In your `AppModule` do you have `providers: [AuthService]` or `imports: [AuthModule]`?

Comment: Yes, I have both

Comment: You shouldn't have `providers: [AuthService]`. That will create a new instance of the`AuthService` and all of its dependencies.

Comment: wow. that was my problem. knew it was something dumb. THANK YOU!

Comment: can you make that an answer so I can select

Comment: I had the same problem. removed AuthService from import in app.module.ts. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After discussion in the comments it was discovered that `AuthService` was being recreated by being added to more than one `providers` array. As the `JwtService` has `@Optional()` options to be injected into it, it didn't fail on re-creation, but it did not get the same options passed to `JwtModule.register`. To rectify this, the`AuthModule` `exports: [AuthService]` and any module that needs the `AuthService` adds `imports: [AuthModule]` to ensure only one `AuthService` is created and it has the proper `JwtService` with the options that are passed to `JwtModule`